# Как получить ответ функции в API SpreadSheet?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Нужно послать запрос с функцией даты =NOW() и получить уже готовый ответ, у меня был этот код и он работал, но я его потерял :(
Если можно приведите пример из Request body на сайте API SpreadSheet

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все что мне надо было, но однако мне это не совсем помогло, это не дает число из своего скрипта в Google таблицах